# How did this person get the console to show below the output pane in jsfiddle?

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle

This person somehow got the developer console to show below the output pane at jsfiddle.  (see http://jsfiddle.net/5ep1fwyL/) However, no matter how many different ways I ask (in Google or other places) I can't seem to get a good straight answer.

Can someone tell me how its done or point me to the doc that explains it?

```
<div class="colors">Red</div>
```

Comment: Tick `Firebug Lite` in JavaScript options.

Comment: Click the icon at the top right corner of 'javascript' panel.

Comment: Click on the "JavaScript"  options toggle at the top-right of the JS editor and select "Firebug Lite".

Comment: Ah-ha!  in the Frameworks & Extensions, select "jQuery (edge)", then the "Firebug Lite" option is displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the JS Fiddle Javascript view, you will notice a cog icon, click this.

You will then be presented with a bunch of options, in the checkbox list under Frameworks, you will see FireBug Lite, enable this and press the Run button.

You should now see the FireBug console window.

Comment: I notice that the checkbox is only available with certain frameworks. jQuery (edge) being one of them.  ... perhaps the only one?

Comment: That is correct.  Its the nightly build of jquery. Since it could be unstable, they include the option to view the console, so you can see exactly the breakdown of what is happening with the new jquery build.  I do not believe this extension exists on any other version of jquery on JSFiddle